# list all Shared folders on Win Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

How do I find all the folders that are shared on Windows Server 2008?

Comment: You should give your question a more meaningful title.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can open a command shell and type:

```
net share
```

Comment: I also just found out that I could go to Start\Programs\Administrative Tools\Share and Storeage Management for this as well.

Answer (score 10):

A quick way is to insert

```
StorageMgmt.msc
```

in your start box. This opens the [Share and Storage Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731574.aspx) Console on Windows Server 2008.

[image]

Comment: This should be the selected answer ^^

Answer (score 3):

In powershell you can use the following:

```
gwmi -Class Win32_Share -ComputerName MyServerName | sort name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know which shared folder corresponds which folder on your system, execute:
compmgmt.msc

[which shared folder corresponds to system folder](http://mis.we.bs/index.php/2011/01/como-saber-que-carpetas-compartidas-corresponden-a-cual-carpeta/)